# Vectorizing numpy calculation without a tensor dot product

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I would like to vectorize a particular case of the following mathematical formula (from Table 2 and Appendix A of [this paper](http://www.strimmerlab.org/publications/journals/shrinkcov2005.pdf)) with `numpy`:

[image: Appendix A]

The case I would like to compute is the following, where the scaling factors under the square root can be ignored.

[image: Table 2]

The term `w_kij - w_ij_bar` is a *n* x *p* x *p* matrix, where *n* is typically much greater than *p*.

I implemented 2 solutions neither of which are particularly good: one involves a double loop, while the other fills the memory with unnecessary calculations very quickly.

```
dummy_data = np.random.normal(size=(100, 5, 5))

# approach 1: a double loop
out_hack = np.zeros((5, 5))
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        out_hack[i, j] = (dummy_data.T[j, j, :]*dummy_data[:, j, i]).sum()

# approach 2: slicing a diagonal from a tensor dot product
out = np.tensordot(dummy_data.T, dummy_data, axes=1)
out = out.diagonal(0, 0, 2).diagonal(0, 0, 2)

print((out.round(6) == out_hack.round(6)).all())
>>> True
```

Is there a way to find middle ground between these 2 approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) translates that almost literally -

```
np.einsum('kjj,kji->ij',dummy_data,dummy_data)
```

Comment: Thank you! The speedup is almost 100x and memory does not seem to be an issue.